# Get order Details from Magento 2 Observer

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, sales-order, product-view

I am trying to build a Magento 2 Order Observer in which I am trying to get the Product Details such as Product ID, Product Name, Product SKU, Product Quantity and Customer Details such as Customer ID, Customer Name, Shipping Address & Phone Number.

Below is my **Observer.php**

```
<?php

namespace My\Plugin\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class LogAddMessage implements ObserverInterface {

protected $_logger;

public function __construct(
\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, array $data = []
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order_id = $order->getID();
    $order_number = $order->getIncrementId();
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $ProdustIds[] = $item->getProductId();
            $ProdustSku[] = $item->getSku();
            $proName[] = $item->getName(); //product name
            $this->_logger->addDebug('Item Name: ' . $item->getName() . 'Item ID: ' . $item->getProductId());
        }
        $proName = json_encode($proName);
        $ProdustSku = json_encode($ProdustSku);
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customer);
        $address = $observer->getShippingAddress();
        $address = json_encode($address);
        $name = $customer->getName(); //customer name
        $this->_logger->addDebug('Order ID: ' . $order_id . ', Products: ' . $proName . ', SKU: ' . $ProdustSku . ', Customer ID: ' . $customerId . ', Customer Name: ' . $name . 'Address: ' . $address);
    }

}
```

On clicking Place Order in Multi Store Magento Website, ***magento_website_url/rest/store_code/V1/guest-carts/cart_id/payment-information*** gives a **500 Internal Server Error**

Comment: Please check log exception to find more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your below line

```
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customer);
```

It should be

```
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);
```

If not solved with this, Post your support log here.

You can see address with

```
$addressObj = $order->getBillingAddress();

echo '<pre>'; print_r($addressObj);
```

For Telephone, Try this

```
$addressObj = $order->getBillingAddress();
$to = $addressObj->getTelephone();
```

Comment: also 
$name = $customer->getName(); //customer name
should be
$name = $customer->getFirstName().' '.$customer->getLastName(); //customer name

Comment: I realised this mistake after checking exception.log  file. I made the changes and I am able to get the Customer name, but I am still not able to get the customer Address and Phone Number.
@Pallavi thanks for your help

Comment: @Anush, Updated my answer. Try that. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get **customer details**, get **Billing details**, get **shipping** details using below code

```
 public function __construct
 (
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
 )
 $this->order = $order;
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
      $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
      $orderid=$order->getEntityId();

      /*get customer details*/

  $custLastName= $orders->getCustomerLastname();
  $custFirsrName= $orders->getCustomerFirstname();
  $ipaddress=$order->getRemoteIp();
  $customer_email=$order->getCustomerEmail();
  $customerid=$order->getCustomerId();

  /* get Billing details */  
  $billingaddress=$order->getBillingAddress();
  $billingcity=$billingaddress->getCity();      
  $billingstreet=$billingaddress->getStreet();
  $billingpostcode=$billingaddress->getPostcode();
  $billingtelephone=$billingaddress->getTelephone();
  $billingstate_code=$billingaddress->getRegionCode();

  /* get shipping details */

  $shippingaddress=$order->getShippingAddress();        
  $shippingcity=$shippingaddress->getCity();
  $shippingstreet=$shippingaddress->getStreet();
  $shippingpostcode=$shippingaddress->getPostcode();      
  $shippingtelephone=$shippingaddress->getTelephone();
  $shippingstate_code=$shippingaddress->getRegionCode();

 /* get  total */

  $tax_amount=$order->getTaxAmount();
  $total=$order->getGrandTotal();
```